# How to redirect a request in spring webflux?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redirect, spring-webflux

how can I create a redirect rest web service in spring WebFlux? It seems that there is no redirect functionality in WebFlux yet!

I want something like this:

```
 @Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> monoRouterFunction() {
    return 
        route(GET("/redirect/{id}"),{
            req -> req.Redirect( fetchAUrlFromDataBase() )
        })
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction() {
     route(GET("/redirect"), { req ->
          ServerResponse.temporaryRedirect(URI.create(TargetUrl))
                    .build()
        }
    })

}
```

Thanks you very much Johan Magnusson

Answer (score 5):

You can add below code in Spring boot main class to redirect '/' request to '/login' page.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse;

import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates.GET;
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctions.route;   

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction() {
        return  route(GET("/"), req ->
                ServerResponse.temporaryRedirect(URI.create("/login"))
                        .build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to achieve this using the code snippet below.
I passed a redirect string to the render function.

The code below redirects to login route.

```
ServerResponse.ok().render("redirect:/login")
```