# How can I add an URL alias for an actuator endpoint with Spring WebFlux?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using Spring Boot 2 with actuator and webflux. And for example I have health endpoint on path `/actuator/health`. I need to make some alias only for health endpoint, so it should be on path `/actuator/health` and also on `/health`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a permanent redirect.

Define a route at `/health` and redirect to `/actuator/health`. Depending on the client it should work.

A sample redirect is described in post [50502377](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502377/how-to-redirect-a-request-in-spring-webflux)